# Why my listview blinks when I perform notifydata setchange

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

My ListView blinks when this code is executed. Is there any method to avoid this?

This is my code:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       for(int i=0;i<getCount();i++){
                           getItem(i).setSelected(false);
                       }
                       getItem(position).setSelected(true);
                       mSelectedOption=getItem(position);
                       notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` if dataset changed. Your code does not reflect such need. And it blinks because it needs to redraw the content to reflect the change (it may or may not be visible, depending on the device, data etc). You may want to profile your code to see what really takes so long you see the UI flickering